# Regex named groups in golang

Tags: regex, go

I need help with integrating a regex with golang.
I want to parse logfiles and created a regex which looks quite fine on https://regex101.com/r/p4mbiS/1/

A logline looks like this:

```
57.157.87.86 - - [06/Feb/2020:00:11:04 +0100] "GET /?parammore=1&customer_id=1&version=1.56&param=meaningful&customer_name=somewebsite.de&some_id=4&cachebuster=1580944263903 HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://www.somewebsite.com/more/andheresomemore/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0"
```

The regex like this:

```
(?P<ip>([^\s]+)).+?\[(?P<localtime>(.*?))\].+?GET\s\/\?(?P<request>.+?)\".+?\"(?P<ref>.+?)\".\"(?P<agent>.+?)\"
```

The result for the named groups shoud look like this:

> ip: 57.157.87.86
>
> localtime: 06/Feb/2020:00:11:04 +0100
>
> request: parammore=1&customer_id=1&...HTTP/1.1
>
> ref: https://www.somewebsite.com/more/andheresomemore/
>
> agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0)...

regex101.com generates the golang code which doesn't work for me. I tried to improve it but no success.

The golang code just returns the entire string not the groups.

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?P<ip>([^\s]+)).+?\[(?P<localtime>(.*?))\].+?GET\s\/\?(?P<request>.+?)\".+?\"(?P<ref>.+?)\".\"(?P<agent>.+?)\"`)
    var str = `57.157.87.86 - - [06/Feb/2020:00:11:04 +0100] "GET /?parammore=1&customer_id=1&version=1.56&param=meaningful&customer_name=somewebsite.de&some_id=4&cachebuster=1580944263903 HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://www.somewebsite.com/more/andheresomemore/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0"`
    
    if len(re.FindStringIndex(str)) > 0 {
        fmt.Println(re.FindString(str),"found at index",re.FindStringIndex(str)[0])
    }
}
```

find the fiddle here https://play.golang.org/p/e0_8PM-Nv6i

Comment: You are using groups, so use `.FindStringSubmatch`

Comment: Check https://play.golang.org/p/iPjqlCzcZDa, is that what you need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Single match solution**

Since you defined capturing groups and need to extract their values, you need to use `.FindStringSubmatch`, see [this Go lang demo](https://play.golang.org/p/Qoej-mZ0UzX):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?P<ip>\S+).+?\[(?P<localtime>.*?)\].+?GET\s/\?(?P<request>.+?)".+?"(?P<ref>.+?)"\s*"(?P<agent>.+?)"`)
    var str = `57.157.87.86 - - [06/Feb/2020:00:11:04 +0100] "GET /?parammore=1&customer_id=1&version=1.56&param=meaningful&customer_name=somewebsite.de&some_id=4&cachebuster=1580944263903 HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://www.somewebsite.com/more/andheresomemore/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0"`
    result := make(map[string]string) 
    match := re.FindStringSubmatch(str) 
    for i, name := range re.SubexpNames() {
        if i != 0 && name != "" {
            result[name] = match[i]
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("IP: %s\nLocal Time: %s\nRequest: %s\nRef: %s\nAgent: %s\n",result["ip"], result["localtime"], result["request"], result["ref"], result["agent"])
}
```

Output:

```
IP: 57.157.87.86
Local Time: 06/Feb/2020:00:11:04 +0100
Request: parammore=1&customer_id=1&version=1.56&param=meaningful&customer_name=somewebsite.de&some_id=4&cachebuster=1580944263903 HTTP/1.1
Ref: https://www.somewebsite.com/more/andheresomemore/
Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0
```

It is not a good idea to use `.+?` so often in the pattern as it decreases performance, thus I replaced those dot patterns with negated character classes and tried to make the pattern a bit more verbose.

**Multiple matches solution**

Here, you need to use [`regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch`](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#Regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch):

See [this Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/IOF_jT5WQnr):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?P<ip>\S+).+?\[(?P<localtime>.*?)\].+?GET\s/\?(?P<request>.+?)".+?"(?P<ref>.+?)"\s*"(?P<agent>.+?)"`)
    var str = `57.157.87.86 - - [06/Feb/2020:00:11:04 +0100] "GET /?parammore=1&customer_id=1&version=1.56&param=meaningful&customer_name=somewebsite.de&some_id=4&cachebuster=1580944263903 HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://www.somewebsite.com/more/andheresomemore/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0"`
    result := make([]map[string]string,0) 
    for _, match := range re.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1) {
        res := make(map[string]string)
        for i, name := range re.SubexpNames() {
            if i != 0 && name != "" {
                res[name] = match[i]
            }
        }
        result = append(result, res)
    }

    // Displaying the matches
    for i, match := range(result) {
        fmt.Printf("--------------\nMatch %d:\n", i+1)
        for i, name := range re.SubexpNames() {
            if i != 0 && name != "" {
                fmt.Printf("Group %s: %s\n", name, match[name]) 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
--------------
Match 1:
Group ip: 57.157.87.86
Group localtime: 06/Feb/2020:00:11:04 +0100
Group request: parammore=1&customer_id=1&version=1.56&param=meaningful&customer_name=somewebsite.de&some_id=4&cachebuster=1580944263903 HTTP/1.1
Group ref: https://www.somewebsite.com/more/andheresomemore/
Group agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0
```

Comment: awesome! Didn't know about the performance issue! I should definetly read more about regex! Great help

Comment: I see the named groups in the pattern but the access to the groups happens using numbers/indexes. I'd expect the access to the groups to happen based on names, too. Otherwise there is no point in using names at all (other than as kind of inline regex comments).

Comment: @konstantin Then what is the type of the output *you* expect? `map[string][]string` for all matches and `map[string]string` for a single match?

Comment: @konstantin Please check the above code, is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regroup` https://github.com/oriser/regroup for that.

Example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/oriser/regroup"
)

type LogEntry struct {
    IP        string `regroup:"ip"`
    LocalTime string `regroup:"localtime"`
    Request   string `regroup:"request"`
    Ref       string `regroup:"ref"`
    Agent     string `regroup:"agent"`
}

func main() {
    var re = regroup.MustCompile(`(?P<ip>([^\s]+)).+?\[(?P<localtime>(.*?))\].+?GET\s\/\?(?P<request>.+?)\".+?\"(?P<ref>.+?)\".\"(?P<agent>.+?)\"`)
    var str = `57.157.87.86 - - [06/Feb/2020:00:11:04 +0100] "GET /?parammore=1&customer_id=1&version=1.56&param=meaningful&customer_name=somewebsite.de&some_id=4&cachebuster=1580944263903 HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "https://www.somewebsite.com/more/andheresomemore/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0"`

    logEntry := &LogEntry{}
    if err := re.MatchToTarget(str, logEntry); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", logEntry)
}
```

<kbd>[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Mjy1cj1q7Me)</kbd>